# Good way to update each item in an array inside a store

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have an array of objects inside my data store in Svelte, I would like to update one property in every single object in the array, i.e. I want to update the author property inside the array in my store to the current user name, this is what I'm currently doing:

```js
let tempArray = $myReviewDataStore;
for(var i=0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
    tempArray[i].author = username;
}
myReviewDataStore.update(data =>{
    return tempArray;
})
```

There must be a better way to do this, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Array.forEach, or Array.map ?. I am not sure they will be any better though. I suppose it depends on your definition of "better". What is wrong with the for loop you already have?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a shorter way to do it:

```
$myReviewDataStore = $myReviewDataStore.map(
 obj => ({...obj, author: username})
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Hm, I guess you don't really need the first part of your logic, as the `data` prop contains the [store value](https://svelte.dev/docs#writable):

> update is a method that takes one argument which is a callback. The callback takes the existing store value as its argument and returns the new value to be set to the store.

So you could shorten it this instead:

```js
myReviewDataStore.update(data => data.map(state => ({...state, author: username }) ));
```